# CompizConfig Question!

Tags: settings, default, ccsm

Problem: Control left click is not opening up a window in a new page.
Reason: I believe it has something to do with CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Could anyone guide me on how to reset CCSM to default settings?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that on the compiz window, under preferences, there is a reset to default button.  I have not tried this, as the last time I mucked with compiz I ended up reinstalling my computer.